# Passing additional (custom) arguments to a bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a twitter bootstrap modal on a page. I need to pass some custom arguments to it. How can I do it? And how do I access them inside the modal?

```
<!-- show modal -->
$("#myModal").modal("show");


<!-- modal -->

#myModal.modal.fade{tabindex: -1, role: :dialog, "aria-labelledby" => "myModalLabel", "aria-hidden" => true}
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        %button{type: :button, class: "close", "data-dismiss" => :modal, "aria-hidden" => true}
          &times;
        %h4.modal-title#myModalLabel
          Choose an address
      .modal-body
        My modal body
      .modal-footer
        %button{type: :button, class: "btn btn-primary"}
          Ok
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try by using the `data-*` attribute and [**jQuery.data() API**](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Set your argument declaratively using `data-*` attribute in your `modal` tag:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-argument="the_argument" ...>
  ...
</div>
```

Or set it programatically using the *jQuery.data() API*:

```
$('#myModal').data('argument', the_argument);
```

Then, to access the argument inside the `modal`, query it using the *jQuery.data() API*:

```
var the_argument = $('#myModal').data('argument');
```

---

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/DRk6C/

Comment: How to pass argument from LINK?